# How do I install MailScanner on 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, installation, configuration, mail-server

I'm attempting to add/install MailScanner to my ubuntu 11.10 desktop configuration running postfix. I tried installing the latest  12.04 LTS but it had neither MailScanner nor qpopper package, 11.10 has qpopper so this is the release I went with.

I went to the MailScanner web site and reviewed the information [here](http://www.mailscanner.info/ubuntu.html) , I then went to http://mailscanner.info/downloads.html and got the version from [here](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mailscanner) .

Well I tried to follow the instructions from the first link  but the MailScanner Package installed a series of configuration files with the suffix of dpkg-new sprinkled throughout the install. Running `dpkg -c mailscanner_4.79.11-2.2_all.deb`shows the files but without this suffix. I'm new to linux and I've clearly missed something but I'm not sure what.

Does anyone know what the best way to get MailScanner installed on 11.10.  I'm aware that the MailScanner package is available for 10.10 and 10.04 but I'd like to run a release that's a bit newer.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I've solved my problem.  I took the generic MailScanner files listed as "Version 4.84.5-2 for Solaris / BSD / Other Linux / Other Unix" and run the install.sh [provided](http://www.mailscanner.info/downloads.html).

I then pulled down the init.d file for Debian Linux package. I had to tweak the init.d file and run update-rc.d a bit.  Once that was done I followed the instructions from [here](http://www.mailscanner.info/ubuntu.html) and tweaked the paths and permissions as needed.

Mail is going in and out with no errors recorded in `/var/log/mail.err`.
Received mail has what looks to be the correct MailScanner message inserted in the header.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Baruwa repo [apt.baruwa.org] simple and easy

```
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/baruwa.list << 'EOF'
```

> ```
> deb http://apt.baruwa.org/ubuntu oneiric main
> EOF
> ```

```
wget -O - http://apt.baruwa.org/baruwa-apt-keys.gpg | apt-key add -
apt-get update
apt-get install mailscanner
```

Answer (score 0):

as you mentioned there is a .DEB file . you can install .DEB file by using

```
sudo dpkg -i mailscanner_4.79.11-2.2_all.deb
```

Thats will installs .deb file . one more thing to install is to opening it with the Ubuntu Software center .

Hope that helps .

Comment: Hello;  I've done the install using that command but it left the config files with a dpkg-new suffix and MailScanner won't start up.  I started to edit the names of the files but it looks as if the post install config never ran.  For example the rc#.d scripts were missing and I had to run update-rc.d. Is there a missing step?

Comment: hi that page have good information . ok could provide us what you have entered and what you got .

Comment: I entered exactly what was in the page.  I got a series of MailScanner configuration files that have a .dpkg-new sufix. Attempting to start MailScanner generates errors.  It also is breaking the dependency maps for ubuntu's software updater.  It's requesting a newer version of perl and complaining about the version installed.  I had to remove Mailscanner to fix that software updater issues.